# How to blur the outline of button?

Tags: css

I am trying to blur the outline of a button without blurring the inside image. The blur filter only applies to the whole image, but I only want the blue outline to be blurred. basically apply the filter: blur(4px) but only on the outline

```
 button:focus {
  outline-color: #054EBA;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}
```

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHIYN.jpg)
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B7Qx.jpg)

Comment: You should use a wrapper because there is no way to do that directly with css

Comment: Use box-shadow?

Comment: If you have a plain color background, you can try a drop-shadow filter + a box-shadow.  `button:focus {
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-color: #054EBA;
  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-offset: 5px;
  box-shadow:0 0 2px 5px white;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 2px #054eba);
}` That's a piece of code to try, it's tricking the drop-shadow area adding a box shadow to avoid to show around the button but blend in the area of the outline. I can make an answer of it if that meets your requirement.

Comment: not quite what I want this doesn't create the same blur effect and it colours the interal picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dispatch the blur effect to another container, it can be pseudo container.

example

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 0em 0.35em;
  color: white;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  font-size:2em;
}

button:focus:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: solid #054eba 2px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<button>?</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Select only the button and not the image inside

Comment: Doesn't button:focus{} do this? i tried filter: blur(4px) but it blurs the whole image